# How can I fix "Command errored out with exit status 1" when installing requirements.txt through pip for a django project?

Tags: python, django, unix, pip, zsh

I'm having trouble installing this requirements.txt file for a Django project.

My project directory looks like this:

```
decker-cms
├── decker_cms
│   ├── account
│   ├── beanstream
│   ├── blog
│   ├── [...project stuff]
├── decker
│   ├── [...env stuff]
```

When I try to run the following command:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

from within the decker_cms directory. I get the following error:

> `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/userk/decker-cms/decker/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1y/pymk85y10l1cfkrh92s3n46h0000gn/T/pip-install-ow_x_27c/reportlab_cb76b6eba8ca413ca98c7cbe92425675/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1y/pymk85y10l1cfkrh92s3n46h0000gn/T/pip-install-ow_x_27c/reportlab_cb76b6eba8ca413ca98c7cbe92425675/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/1y/pymk85y10l1cfkrh92s3n46h0000gn/T/pip-record-3hnbigmk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/userk/decker-cms/decker/include/site/python3.9/reportlab Check the logs for full command output.`

I installed the project prerequisites: gif, python, pip3, Postgres 10.10 and npm. How can I go about solving this?

I'm using a 2020 M1 Macbook Pro.

Comment: The error message you present says at the end *Check the logs for full command output.* With what you have shown, all anyone can say is *Something went wrong.*

Comment: @BoarGules How can I do so? I'm quite new to this